# facing issue while stack is deployed with updated image fromm jenkins, service is not up (0/1) ps --no-trunc says volume mounting error

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, rsync, samba

I do not understand why is this volume mounting error is occuring
I am not able to rectify this error

I am deploying a docker-compose.yml
containing a service rsync,clean,monitor
latest image of that branch is pulled
environment variable and paths are set

all the other services are up
except rsync
ps --no-trunc shows below error

I am using samba share to copy files from local to remote
using rsync - cronjob is set for every 1 min on remote ip

stack is deployed on machine A and samba share on machine B
in order to receive files from machine B shared Dir to machine A's local dir

> docker.website.com/mindconnectrail/filecollector/rsync:SSA-refactoring-send-file-feature   mcrtest-m4   Shutdown        Failed 1 second ago      "starting container failed: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/filecopy_samba-com1-share/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //172.19.1.79/aashlesh:/var/lib/docker/volumes/filecopy_samba-com1-share/_data, flags: 0x1, data: vers=3.02,mfsymlinks,username=usr,password=pass,domain=WORKGROUP: permission denied"